# How to fake signalR connection for unit test

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, signalr

We have a webservice which provides real time data for our application. In order to connect to that webservice we use $.connection. Code for that will be like -

```
this.myConnect = $.connection(myURL);
this.myConnect.start(settingsWhichIncludesACallBack).fail(anotherfunction);
```

How can I spy on the start and connection method. In other words, I don't want to establish an actual connection to the webService but still would like that my callback (passed as settings) to be call.

I am trying to use Jasmine spies to call fake for $.connection but for obvious reasons it fails on this.myConnect.start as 'not a function' for type error.

Answer (score 3):

I've ran into this same issue before and used [this](http://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/mocking-signalr-client-for-better-unit-testing/) article to create a mock signalR client. I actually copied the exact script from that site and included the mock in my config instead of the actual signalR client. The article has a decent write up on how he used the mock to write unit tests and there is a link at the bottom to some examples of unit tests that the author wrote using the mock client.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `IHubCallerConnectionContext` interface to create a mock object to simulate your hub methods for testing.

Check out this link : 
[Unit Testing SignalR Applications](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-signalr-applications)

Comment: The interface mentioned exists on the back end but not on the front end. This question is about unit testing the front end (JavaScript).